# How to generate random points within a circular area, with higher density near the center?

Tags: python

We want the probability of a point being generated to be higher the closer to the center the point is. Therefore, most of the points would gather around the center of the circle.

So far, I have done something like this:

```py
t = random.random() * 2 * math.pi
r = random.random() * radius
new_x = x_center + r * math.cos(t)
new_y = y_center + r * math.sin(t)
```

Comment: Generally, you want to sample uniformly in some interval and then come up with a skewed mapping from values in that interval to points on your circle

Comment: @trincot I added what I've tried and made it more specific instead of providing an example.

Comment: So what is the issue? Why does this code not provide what you need?

Comment: @trincot The points do not follow this non-symmetrical distribution where they tend to gather around the center. My thoughts are that I have to balance "r" (not radius, the variable r above) in a way that reflects this skewed distribution, but I might be completely mistaken.

Comment: Your code will already result in a higher density at the center. Did you plot 1000 generated points and see?

Comment: @trincot You are right, but for 10^4 points the circle is almost full. I guess there might be a lot more overlapping points around the center than further from it, but I'd like the circumference a lot more sparse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your algorithm already results in a higher density at the center.

You can influence the density by raising `random.random()` to a variable power where you use it for defining `r`

So for instance, you could do this:

```
attraction = 3  # play with this value
t = random.random() * 2 * math.pi
r = random.random() ** attraction * radius  # <--
new_x = x_center + r * math.cos(t)
new_y = y_center + r * math.sin(t)
```

Here is an interactive demo of the algorithm in JavaScript, where you can play with the additional parameter and see what it gives:

```js
let x_center = 80,
    y_center = 80,
    radius = 80;

function refresh(attraction=1) {
    clear();
    // Plot 10^4 random points in a disc
    for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        let t = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI
        let r = Math.random() ** attraction * radius
        let new_x = x_center + r * Math.cos(t)
        let new_y = y_center + r * Math.sin(t)
        plot(new_x, new_y);
    }
}


// I/O handling (would be different in Python)

let input = document.querySelector("input");
let canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function plot(x, y) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x, y);
    ctx.lineTo(x + 0.5, y + 0.5);
    ctx.stroke();
}

function clear() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

input.addEventListener("input", () => refresh(input.value));
refresh(input.value);
```

```css
input { width: 4em }
div { text-align: center }
```

```html
<input type="number" value="1.0" step="0.1"><br>
<div><canvas width="160" height="160"></canvas></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide a solution as well as creating an interactive plot. Much appreciated! Have a nice day.